# main.py return empty response

Tags: python, html, flask

I wrote a simple python with flask code, where i tried to get one user id as a input, and tried to print the same as output.But it returns and empty page.

Here is the main.py file

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,Response
from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin
import flask_monitoringdashboard as dashboard

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG']=True
dashboard.bind(app)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
@cross_origin()
def home():
    return render_template('userid.html')

@app.route("/recommend",methods=['GET','POST'])
def uploadfiles():
    upload_value=request.form.get('number',type=int)
    return Response(upload_value)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
     app.run(port = 8000)
```

---

### Here is the userid.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Recommendation System</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="background-color:DodgerBlue;"></h1>
<h2> Course Recommendation System</h2>
<h3>Enter User ID to see recommended courses</h3>
    <form action='/recommend' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Enter your userID:</label>
        <input type="number" name="number" required />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to receive one int input from flask form page and i would like to print the same as output. But it returns and empty page`

Answer (score 0):

try indexing instead of the get function. For some reason that worked for me.

replace this:

```
upload_value = request.form.get('numberUser',type=int)
```

with this:

```
upload_value = request.form['number']
```